# Does anyone know why the designer of Redux use function instead of class to write Redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am very curious about the pros and cons of using the function like below instead of creating a new class instance for Redux store. What is the consideration behind this design?

```
function reducer(state="gg", action){
    if(action == "a"){
        return "apple"
    }

    return state
}

function createStore(reducer) {
    var state;
    var listeners = []


    function getState() {
        return state
    }

    function subscribe(listener) {
        listeners.push(listener)
        return function unsubscribe() {
            var index = listeners.indexOf(listener)
            listeners.splice(index, 1)
        }
    }

    function dispatch(action) {
        state = reducer(state, action)
        listeners.forEach(listener => listener())
    }

    dispatch({})

    return { dispatch, subscribe, getState }
}
```

reference: https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/

Comment: Just preference I think. Quite a lot of ppl like functional paradigm better. Especially when redux is apparently a functional style lib.

Comment: Same logic could be written in OOP style but with no obvious gain. First off, you don’t want the API to be `store.dispatch` but just `dispatch` right? Then there’s extra work of binding `this` context compare to FP style. Dealing with `this` is quite a headache in JS.

Comment: It would be better to [ask him directly](https://twitter.com/acemarke) as this question can't be answered with facts on Stack Overflow, since it's based on opinions _of someone else_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Good Question:

Class instances for action objects and reducers are not supported because class instances make serialization and deserialization tricky. **Deserialization** methods like JSON.parse(string) will return a plain old JavaScript object rather than class instances.

**Serialization** enables the browser to store all actions that have been dispatched, as well as the previous store states, with much less memory. Rewinding and 'hot reloading' the store is central to the Redux developer **experience** and the function of Redux DevTools. This also enables deserialized actions to be stored on the server and re-serialized in the browser in the case of server-side rendering with Redux.

Comment: Perfect Explanation Yash!!!!!

Comment: This is completely unrelated to why Redux uses functions instead.

Comment: okkk,I was try to explain Some Documentation Terms... I will come with Nice Example I think then You get point. Thank you For Suggestions Emile Bergeron